# How to organise React components and containers for routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am beginning learning React (with redux and react-router) and wondering how to organize my app (classical "navabar with login/register control at top, sidebar with items and content area).

I assume to use following structure of components (containers? what is correct term?):

```
App (it is container)
|=> NavBar
  |=>LoginRegisterContainer (if user not authentified)
    |=> Login (email, password, button "login", Link "or register")
    |=> Register (email, password, name, button "register, Link "or login")
    |=> PickAControl (Link "login", text "or", Link "register, each clicked reveals corresponding control and hides another one)
  |=> Profile menu (link to "my profile" and item "logout")
|=> Sidebar
  |=> Users (Link from "react-router" with "active" state)
  |=> Exams (Link from "react-router" with "active" state)
  ...
|=> UsersList
  |=> UserRow
  |=> UserRow
  ...
|=> ExamsList
  |=> ExamRow
  |=> ExamRow
  ...
```

Now I want to user `react-router` to, fo instance, be able to show "login" control on navbar by `localhost:3000/login` or users list (once authentified) by `localhost:3000/users`.

As I understand I should implement routing table like that:

```
render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>

      <Route path="/" component={NavBar}>
        <Route path="/" component={LoginRegisterContainer }>
          /* Section should be should only for unauthenticated users */
          <Route path="/" component={PickAControl }> /* 1. How to show it by default and hide once once of routes below navigated? */
          <Route path="/login" component={Login}>
          <Route path="/login" component={Register}>

          /* 2. how to show `Profile` control/container for authenticated users? */
        </Route>
      </Route>

      <Route path="/" component={Sidebar} />
      <Route path="/users" component={Users}/>
      <Route path="/exams" component={Exams}/>
    </Router>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

I found how to show/hide controls like `Login` and `Register` and `PickAControl` when it implemented in one container via state. But how to do it via router?

I completely confused whether showing of `Profile` control is responsibility of Router? Or I should somehow say to `NavBar` that user already logged on?

I almost implemented it without `react-router` but conception of `{this.props.children}` is not understandable for me. I.e. I know how to render control/container in `render` function. But how achieve it with router? Samples from `react-router-tutorial` did not clarified it because it container only very simple and meaningless controls.

So my question is how to implement desired scheme correctly? Or how to fix my schema to do it more react-way?

Comment: why not pass a prop in the route? and then read it from the component?

Comment: @AvraamMavridis I do not understand how it should be done. And second option: usage of `withRoute` look ugly.